# Moving the Search Bar to specific location in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the search bar that appears at the center of the page. I would like to move it up 1/4 of the way. How do I achieve this? The code is below.

Update:

Using Developer Tools in Chrome, I am able to make it work temporarily by using the following steps:

1. Inspect Element to get "Developer Tools"
2. Uncheck "display: table-cell;" in .intro .intro-body
3. Click on "element.style"
4. Type "margin-top: 300px;"

I can now play around with the position of the search bar. However, whenever i refresh the browser everything is lost!

Thanks!

```
 <!-- Intro Header -->
    <header class="intro">
        <div class="intro-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        </form>
                        <form action="/predict" style="width: 500px; margin: 0.3em 2em;" method='POST'>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="user_input" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Indie Games">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Recommend</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

The associated CSS file can be found here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23725837/bootstrap.css

This is how the whole thing looks like:

[image]

The custom CSS is here:

/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Grayscale Bootstrap Theme (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

```
> body {
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 100%;
>     font-family: Lora,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
>     color: #fff;
>     background-color: #000; }
> 
> html {
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 100%; }
> 
> h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
>     margin: 0 0 35px;
>     text-transform: uppercase;
>     font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
>     font-weight: 700;
>     letter-spacing: 1px; }
> 
> p {
>     margin: 0 0 25px;
>     font-size: 18px;
>     line-height: 1.5; }
> 
> @media(min-width:768px) {
>     p {
>         margin: 0 0 35px;
>         font-size: 20px;
>         line-height: 1.6;
>     } }
> 
> a {
>     color: #42dca3;
>     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
>     -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
>     transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
> 
> a:hover, a:focus {
>     text-decoration: none;
>     color: #1d9b6c; }
> 
> .light {
>     font-weight: 400; }
> 
> .navbar-custom {
>     margin-bottom: 0;
>     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
>     text-transform: uppercase;
>     font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
>     background-color: #000; }
> 
> .navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
>     font-weight: 700; }
> 
> .navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
>     outline: 0; }
> 
> .navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle {
>     padding: 4px 6px;
>     font-size: 16px;
>     color: #fff; }
> 
> .navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-custom
> .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:active {
>     outline: 0; }
> 
> .navbar-custom a {
>     color: #fff; }
> 
> .navbar-custom .nav li a {
>     -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
>     -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
>     transition: background .3s ease-in-out; }
> 
> .navbar-custom .nav li a:hover {
>     outline: 0;
>     color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
>     background-color: transparent; }
> 
> .navbar-custom .nav li a:focus, .navbar-custom .nav li a:active {
>     outline: 0;
>     background-color: transparent; }
> 
> .navbar-custom .nav li.active {
>     outline: 0; }
> 
> .navbar-custom .nav li.active a {
>     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3); }
> 
> .navbar-custom .nav li.active a:hover {
>     color: #fff; }
> 
> @media(min-width:768px) {
>     .navbar-custom {
>         padding: 20px 0;
>         border-bottom: 0;
>         letter-spacing: 1px;
>         background: 0 0;
>         -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
>         -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
>         transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
>     }
> 
>     .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
>         padding: 0;
>         border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
>         background: #000;
>     } }
> 
> .intro {
>     display: table;
>     width: 100%;
>     height: auto;
>     padding: 100px 0;
>     text-align: center;
>     color: #fff;
>     background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
>     background-color: #000;
>     -webkit-background-size: cover;
>     -moz-background-size: cover;
>     background-size: cover;
>     -o-background-size: cover; }
> 
> .intro .intro-body {
>     display: table-cell;
>     vertical-align: middle; }
> 
> .intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
>     font-size: 40px; }
> 
> .intro .intro-body .intro-text {
>     font-size: 18px; }
> 
> @media(min-width:768px) {
>     .intro {
>         height: 100%;
>         padding: 0;
>     }
> 
>     .intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
>         font-size: 80px;
>     }
> 
>     .intro .intro-body .intro-text {
>         font-size: 26px;
>     } }
> 
> .btn-circle {
>     width: 70px;
>     height: 70px;
>     margin-top: 15px;
>     padding: 7px 16px;
>     border: 2px solid #fff;
>     border-radius: 100%!important;
>     font-size: 40px;
>     color: #fff;
>     background: 0 0;
>     -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
>     -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
>     transition: background .3s ease-in-out; }
> 
> .btn-circle:hover, .btn-circle:focus {
>     outline: 0;
>     color: #fff;
>     background: rgba(255,255,255,.1); }
> 
> .btn-circle i.animated {
>     -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
>     -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
>     -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
>     -moz-transition-duration: 1s; }
> 
> .btn-circle:hover i.animated {
>     -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
>     -moz-animation-name: pulse;
>     -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
>     -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
>     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
>     -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
>     -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
>     -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; }
> 
> @-webkit-keyframes pulse {    
>     0% {
>         -webkit-transform: scale(1);
>         transform: scale(1);
>     }
> 
>     50% {
>         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
>         transform: scale(1.2);
>     }
> 
>     100% {
>         -webkit-transform: scale(1);
>         transform: scale(1);
>     } }
> 
> @-moz-keyframes pulse {    
>     0% {
>         -moz-transform: scale(1);
>         transform: scale(1);
>     }
> 
>     50% {
>         -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
>         transform: scale(1.2);
>     }
> 
>     100% {
>         -moz-transform: scale(1);
>         transform: scale(1);
>     } }
> 
> .content-section {
>     padding-top: 100px; }
> 
> .download-section {
>     width: 100%;
>     padding: 50px 0;
>     color: #fff;
>     background: url(../img/downloads-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
>     background-color: #000;
>     -webkit-background-size: cover;
>     -moz-background-size: cover;
>     background-size: cover;
>     -o-background-size: cover; }
> 
> #map {
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 200px;
>     margin-top: 100px; }
> 
> @media(min-width:767px) {
>     .content-section {
>         padding-top: 250px;
>     }
> 
>     .download-section {
>         padding: 100px 0;
>     }
> 
>     #map {
>         height: 400px;
>         margin-top: 250px;
>     } }
> 
> .btn {
>     border-radius: 0;
>     text-transform: uppercase;
>     font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
>     font-weight: 400;
>     -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
>     -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
>     transition: all .3s ease-in-out; }
> 
> .btn-default {
>     border: 1px solid #42dca3;
>     color: #42dca3;
>     background-color: transparent; }
> 
> .btn-default:hover, .btn-default:focus {
>     border: 1px solid #42dca3;
>     outline: 0;
>     color: #000;
>     background-color: #42dca3; }
> 
> ul.banner-social-buttons {
>     margin-top: 0; }
> 
> @media(max-width:1199px) {
>     ul.banner-social-buttons {
>         margin-top: 15px;
>     } }
> 
> @media(max-width:767px) {
>     ul.banner-social-buttons li {
>         display: block;
>         margin-bottom: 20px;
>         padding: 0;
>     }
> 
>     ul.banner-social-buttons li:last-child {
>         margin-bottom: 0;
>     } }
> 
> footer {
>     padding: 50px 0; }
> 
> footer p {
>     margin: 0; }
> 
> ::-moz-selection {
>     text-shadow: none;
>     background: #fcfcfc;
>     background: rgba(255,255,255,.2); }
> 
> ::selection {
>     text-shadow: none;
>     background: #fcfcfc;
>     background: rgba(255,255,255,.2); }
> 
> img::selection {
>     background: 0 0; }
> 
> img::-moz-selection {
>     background: 0 0; }
> 
> body {
>     webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2); }
```

Comment: That link goes to a Bootstrap 3 CSS file: you should post the custom CSS related to your question and any other code that is relevant to the position of your search input.

Comment: the CSS file does not contain any information related to `.intro` nor `.intro-body` which seem to be the culprits here... any other custom CSS you may be using?

Comment: Just added a custom CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you downloaded the custom CSS file (for the Grayscale Bootstrap Theme), you can change the `.intro .intro-body` entry to:

```
.intro .intro-body {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle; 
     margin-top: 300px;  /* adjust your value here as desired */
}
```

If you did not (and you are linking to the theme somewhere else, like a CDN), you can create your own CSS file with only this entry (as above) and include it to your site *after* the custom CSS file (effectively, overriding the theme's value)

Comment: It works when I remove display: table-cell; Without removing there is no change. Is it OK to remove display: table-cell?

Comment: Sure, if you are not using the same class anywhere else in your site.

Comment: Thanks...! I am glad I could help